# Excel VBA code to return weekday name from a date then autofilters for userdefined weekdays and copies autofiltered data to new sheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, autofilter, weekday, vba

I spent last night looking for an answer to my question but i didn't find anything specific to my ask.

I have a huge sheet that contains lots of data.  In Column A, I have the Date and time. I would like to have a VBA code that does few actions.

1) Insert a column B next to column A that gives the weekday name. For example if the date in column A is January 10, 2016 8:30  then column B will have "Sunday"

2) Then the VBA code to filter this sheet based on Column B. For instance given a user input of a particular day (example Friday), the autofilter will filter for 4 days ahead ( Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday ).

3) The result of the autofilter then is copied to new blank sheet.

4) In the new sheet I want the vba to delete any row data for the same user defined day ( example Friday ) that has time of less than user defined time (example 8:00 am) in Column A. Finally shifting cells up to remove any blank rows.

Hope I am not overwhelming you with this problem, but I hope I get feedback from one of the brilliant minds in here

Here it the code attempted for part 1

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns()
Worksheets("Imported").Activate
'Inserting a Column at Column B
If Range("B1").Value = "Weekday" Then
Range("B1").Value = "Weekday1"
Else
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("B1").Value = "Weekday"
Worksheets("Imported").Range("B2").Formula = "=choose(weekday(A2),""Sunday"",""Monday"",""Tuesday"",""Wednesday"",""Thursday"",""Friday"",""Saturday"")"
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2").Copy Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could start by using 'Werkday' function mentioned in link below. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/weekday.php

Comment: I tried Range("B2").Formula= "=choose(weekday(a1),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")" but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**This is only to get you started.**

If **A2** contains a genuine Excel date/time, then in **B1** enter:

```
=TEXT(A2,"dddd")
```

[image]

If you want a *VBA* macro to accomplish your project, start by turning on the macro recorder and performing the task once manually.

You will then have a macro that you can begin to optimize and generalize.

Comment: Now I managed to have the VBA code to 1) Insert a column B next to column A that gives the weekday name. For example if the date in column A is January 10, 2016 8:30 then column B will have "Sunday"

Now I need help to attempt remaining 2,3,4 questions in my original post

Comment: Sub sbInsertingColumns()
Worksheets("Imported").Activate
'Inserting a Column at Column B
If Range("B1").Value = "Weekday" Then
Range("B1").Value = "Weekday1"
Else
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("B1").Value = "Weekday"
Worksheets("Imported").Range("B2").Formula = "=choose(weekday(A2),""Sunday"",""Monday"",""Tuesday"",""Wednesday"",""Thursday"",""Friday"",""Saturday"")"
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2").Copy Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
End If

End Sub

Comment: @exlover You need to put any code you are trying in the original post.  It is easier to format and read.